# What is the best way of encrypting large files for a corporate use case?

Tags: gnupg

We are creating backups that contain user information. Even though it is created in a closed environment, if there is a breach in our backup systems we would like to make it harder to use the stolen data. We are using GPG as the current solution but I have seen several security people arguing against it.

Example:
http://secushare.org/PGP

My understanding is that most of the time these people advising against GPG only for the message encryption use case and not against the file encryption one (especially in a closed system).

Should I consider using something else or GPG is just fine.

Comment: Most of that post is not relevant to your case as it is about email transmission. I assume that you are not using email for your backups? Without knowing the sensitivity of your data and what backup system you are using, it isn't possible to give an answer here. Generically, PGP is OK if your backups are kept offline but then a simple password might be as well. Many commercial backup tools have their own encryption scheme. Other advise depends on platform, software, backup-set size storage and data sensitivity.